# Can't get my CPU or GPU in the system preference

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have finally manage to buy myself a new laptop a Dell Inspiron i7 Second Gen. I have installed my favorite Linux Distribution "LinuxMint", and have all my hardware installed properly. I have Blender 2.79b and all is good. But when I go to my User Preference -> System, I cannot select any compute device!

[image]

If I check my OS info, I get the CPU info and my Intel Graphics car info, but not my GPU;

[image]

I have check at the command line that my GPU is well installed, when I run the command "lshw -c video" I can see my Radeon R5 listed:

[image]

Now I understand that not all GPU are supported, but I would thought that I can at least select my CPU! If anyone could help with this issue. I have looked at the CUDA driver but cuda supports only NVIDIA if I am not mistaken. Any other help will be welcome?

My Apologies if my question is in the wrong thread.
Thank you kindly

Comment: While cuda is nvidia only, amd gpus can use opencl which should also work with Intels built in gpus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual

When set to None or when the only option is None: the CPU will be used as the computing device for the Cycles Renderer.

Comment: Thanks a million, I did not know that! Cool bean now I can start using blender...

Comment: You're welcome and enjoy Blender.